# How do I sort the strings I have in a textfile properly?

Tags: c#, sorting, io, console-application, streamreader

So I've setup a streamreader to read from a textfile
then it saves the lines it reads in a string variable.
then I want to print out those lines in a alphabetical order to the console
I've tried adding the lines to a list then doing list.sort but that didnt work.

> The list is just a list of names such as
>  Daniel
>  Brian
>   Sarah
>  Johnny

```
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToTextfile);
            {

                string row;

                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();

                List<string> theList = new List<string>();
                theList.Add(line);




                while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] fält = row.Split('\t');
                    string namn = fält[0];
                    int ålder = int.Parse(fält[1]);
                    string spelarPosition = (fält[2]);
                    int tröjNummer = int.Parse(fält[3]);

                    spelarInfo sinfo = new spelarInfo();
                    sinfo.namn = namn;
                    sinfo.ålder = ålder;
                    sinfo.spelarPosition = spelarPosition;
                    sinfo.tröjNummer = tröjNummer;


                }
Console.WriteLine(theList);
```

it throws me this error.
[image]
How do I properly do this?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
var arr = File.ReadAllLines(pathToTextfile);
foreach(var item in arr.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Note: `OrderBy` creates a query which does not alter your original array.

If you do not mind your original array getting modified then simply use `Array.Sort`

```
Array.Sort(arr);
```

Comment: That works perfectly! But I dont really understand this part ```(x => x)```

Comment: That is a lambda, just telling the OrderBy method the criteria to sort.

Comment: It is unfortunate to use OrderBy of Linq to sort a simple string array, as it creates a new collection. It is better to use specific sort of an array. No need to Linq, nor lambda. See my response.

Comment: @gentiane - well it depends on use case. I find it safe to sort copies of arrays which keep my original array intact for later re-use if required.

Comment: @Sadiq Ok if need of original array is necessary. But it was not a requirement of the question. If not necessary, it is better to use Array specific methods; people tend to overuse linq without knowing what is going on behind it.

Comment: @gentiane - Sure i understand, i added that as an edit in my answer.

Comment: Sadiq it still doesnt really make sense to me sorry

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson - its difficult to explain in a comment box, would suggest this [primer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT7FZvgMDfo)

Answer (score 0):

To read each line and sort them :

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
Array.Sort(lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a fuller example. I suggest you store a list of your players type rather a list of strings.

```
   Player p1 = new Player() { Name = "BOOP", Age = 25 };
   Player p2 = new Player() { Name = "ZOOP", Age = 21 };
   Player p3 = new Player() { Name = "DOOP", Age = 25 };
   Player p4 = new Player() { Name = "FOOP", Age = 28 };

   List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

   players.Add(p1);
   players.Add(p2);
   players.Add(p3);
   players.Add(p4);

   var sortedByName = players.OrderBy(player => player.Name);
   var sortedByAge = players.OrderBy(player => player.Age);
```

This way you have more control over over how to order your list and you are already creating some sort of player object so why just store the name.

Comment: I don treally understand this part 'player => player.Name' , would you mind explaining it a bit? Like dumb it down alot haha

Comment: Its a lambda expression. It means we can access a players properties here. it doesnt matter what we call it because we its of type player ( x => x.Name) would work just as well.

Comment: oh okay, but how does this work? foreach(var item in arr.OrderBy(x => x)), how does the x take place here? "See the example answer above"

Comment: Its implicit. You can use ((Player player) => player.Name) if you would like to be explicit.